# How to define a function that receive a async closure as parameter without a where clause

Tags: asynchronous, rust, where-clause

When trying to write a function that receives a async closure, I found it is a little bit tricky.

I know correct version is

```rust
pub async fn f1<F, Fut>(f: F) -> u32
where
    F: Fn(u32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = u32>,
{
    f(9u32).await
}
```

However, the `where` clause in the Rust doc saying that it is just a convenient way to express those type, so I tried to remove the where clause like this:

```rust
pub async fn f2(f: Fn(u32) -> Future<Output = u32>) -> u32 {
    f(9u32).await
}
```

To my surprise, Rust refused to compile it, saying that

```
error: trait objects must include the dyn keyword
```

Anyone know what is the correct way to remove the `where` clause?

Any magic is played here by the `where` clause?

Comment: I think you read it backwards: your second snippet is a convenient way to express the first one, for simple cases. For more complex cases, such as yours, you have to revert back to the full `where` syntax.

Comment: The doc said: "using a where clause is more expressive than using normal syntax". So I know it is more expressive, but in this specify case, I cannot see any different in the second version, unless the "where" clause does something that we cannot see.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't like that "normal syntax" part. I consider the `where` syntax the _normal_ one, and the inline the _alternative_. But I see that your issue here is that the `Fn` and the `Future` traits are treated differently... let me develop that into an answer.

Comment: And actually, if my understanding is correct, `where` is more like the normal syntax

Answer (score 5):

In your first snippet you have to constraints:

- `F` must implement `Fn(u32) -> Fut`.
- `Fut` must implement `Future<Output = u32>`.

But in your second snippet there are no constraints. The syntax for an inline constraint is with the `impl` keyword:

```
pub async fn f2(f: impl Fn(u32) -> Future<Output = u32>) -> u32 {
    f(9u32).await
}
```

This doesn't work either because the `impl` applies to the `Fn` trait only, not to the return trait, so the compiler complains that a naked trait is not allowed, that you should add `dyn` to it.

Bad advice, because:

```
pub async fn f2(f: impl Fn(u32) -> dyn Future<Output = u32>) -> u32 {
    f(9u32).await
}
```

will not work either, because `dyn Trait` types are unsized and cannot be returned.

You could try another `impl` there, that usually works in return types but:

```
pub async fn f2(f: impl Fn(u32) -> impl Future<Output = u32>) -> u32 {
    f(9u32).await
}
```

> impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and method return types

The only syntax I know of to constraint the return type of an `Fn` trait is with the `where` syntax:

```
pub async fn f2<Fut>(f: impl Fn(u32) -> Fut) -> u32
where
    Fut: Future<Output = u32>,
{
    f(9u32).await
}
```

But now that you are in full `where` mode, I see little reason to keep the inline constraint. Personally I consider bad style having both syntaxes on the same function.

Comment: Thank you @rodrigo, I think in this case the `Fut` is a must that we cannot really inline the constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referencing [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/where.html):

The example there doesn't use trait objects (e.g. `foo: Box<dyn SomeTrait>`) or existential types (e.g. `foo: impl SomeTrait`) but adds bounds to generic types at the declaration site:

```rust
impl <A: TraitB + TraitC, D: TraitE + TraitF> MyTrait<A, D> for YourType {}

// Expressing bounds with a `where` clause
impl <A, D> MyTrait<A, D> for YourType where
    A: TraitB + TraitC,
    D: TraitE + TraitF {}
```

In your case, you'd be writing:

```rust
pub async fn f2<F: Fn(u32) -> Fut, Fut: std::future::Future<Output = u32>>(f: F) -> u32 {
    f(9u32).await
}
```

instead of putting the `Fn(u32) -> Future<Output = u32>` bound as the type of `f`. Note that you also need to declare a generic type `Fut: Future<Output = u32>` for the returned future from the closure, otherwise you'd be returning a raw trait object again.

As mentioned by @rodrigo, it's also possible to use the `impl SomeTrait` notation to entirely remove the generic type parameter from the function.